# Using dd to clone drive looks stuck

Tags: dd

I ran `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress conv=sync,noerror`
and it froze almost immediately. But I left the terminal open, and in another terminal I can see two processes with that command in htop. But I tried `sudo kill -USR1` with both the PIDs I got from htop and it didn't return anything with either. Is there any other way to tell if anything is happening with this? Thanks.

Comment: `dmesg` will probably show tons of IO errors which could indicate a HW failure.

Comment: [dd conv=sync,noerror (or conv=noerror,sync) corrupts your data.](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171)

Comment: You can also check offsets with lsof and the like...

Comment: use `pv` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) to get progress, like this `dd if=/dev/sda | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb options`

Comment: @Bart Is there a way to do that for a process that's already in progress?

Comment: @frostschutz Here's what I get when I run that command for the drives. sda is the source drive and sdb is the destination
`dd      2260 root    0r   BLK    8,0 0xa000000  140 /dev/sda`
`dd      2260 root    1w   BLK   8,16 0x9c00000  411 /dev/sdb`

Comment: I can only guess that sdb somehow has a problem writing the 0x9c00000-0xa000000 block (156-160MiB in), anything at all in dmesg? You should cancel that dd command anyway

Comment: @frostschutz There's a ton of stuff in `dmesg`, I don't know what's relevant and didn't want to dump a wall of text in here. I'll probably just pull these drives and do the clone in something with a GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.